# Calculate on cron expression

Tags: node.js, cron, crontrigger

Is there any library to calculate cron expression in nodejs? like add or subtract hours from cron expression

For example:

1. If you have cron expression "0 23 * * *", it will trigger at 23:00 everyday, then have a function add 2 hours to the cron and it will result at "0 1 * * *", trigger at 01:00 every day after addition.
2. If you have cron expression "0 23 31 12 ?", it will trigger at 23:00 31/12 every year, then you add 4 hours to that cron and it will result at "0 3 01 01 ?" will trigger 03:00 01/01 every year after addition.

The case I meet is when I have a job trigger at 23:00 every day, I will automatically set another job after 2 hours. The result that I will have 2 job: one for 23:00 every day, one for 01:00 next every day (2 hour later)

I don't know is it possible to do it. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: can you try this 0 23,02 * * *  ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but 0 23,2 * * * will trigger on 2:00 23:00 every day but my case is I'm only have 23:00 everyday and the 2 hours later as input, my expected output is we have 2 cron 0 23 * * * and 0 1 * * * (2 hours later from 23:00)